# How i can share information from my MicroService A's postgers DB to MicroService B

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, microservices

I have created Four micro services. First service only handles registration n login  module(A), Seconds service has the Post& Comment Module(B),Third services has Rating & Review Module (C)and ADMIN Module (D).

**Problem**

All micro services has their own database.But Service B is dependent to service A's DB. Service C is dependent to B and A's  DB  and Service D is also dependent to service A,B,C. I'm using postgres DB for all service A,B,C .

**Option 1.**
I can use JDBC connection Factory and connect service B to service A DB.But this is not a good practice b'coz if Service A changed their column then we have to change Service B module.

**Option 2.**
I can create Hot-standby replica of my service A and Service B but the problem here Hot-standby replica is Read Only i can't perform update n delete.

Comment: Simply expose API in service A and call this API from service B to get the data. You can use CACHE on postgres in service A for better performance.

Comment: Have you read the `Database per service` and `Sagas` pattern? https://microservices.io/patterns/data/database-per-service.html https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should design your microservices so they don't need any dependency on other microservices. Otherwise it looks like distributed monolith. No matter if dependency is established on microservice level or any kind of database linking as both your options suggest.

IMHO the clean solution is:

1. think over again if you really need such granularity
2. if yes, then for each database, declare all entities needed by particular microservice. Duplicities are not problem - if B module (posts) needs database of users, let it have it's own copy of users table, not link to A module.
3. connect microservices by reliable messaging system (Kafka) in which an event in one microservice propagates to listeners in other microservices and let them update their data models

There is a lot of redundancy in this model, however it's robust and definitely closer to really distributed system. We successfully use it in our big fintech platform.

Comment: Great answer. Two things I'd add to this: 1. The services that are keeping a copy of the data don't need to keep an exact copy, but just the parts they're interested in. 2. Realise that these copies are essentially just caches of data the service doesn't own. Never update the data that the service doesn't own (except when the owning service says it's changed).

Comment: Thanks to both of you @Tomas